# Data are overlapping when i am scrolling in UItableview...why?

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, xml-parsing

I have `UItableview` where every cell containing 5 cell and these cell are representing some parsed xml data.When `UITableview` execute at the start of the view controller then it shows the correct data in correct cell from an `NSMutableArray` but now my problem is when scroll to fresh data for update data from the xml file then data becoming scattered different cell representing different data.if i explain then..

First cell so index number one but after refreshing the table cell 1 showing the data cell 5 or any other cell thats mean cell are not overlapping actually but its data are representing on wrong way..i am not finding the solution please anybody help me....

Here is my code of tableview cell

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;


    cellView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,8,290, 120)] autorelease];
    cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cellView.tag =10;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 40, 48, 48)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"productbox.png"];
    imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    imgView.tag = 5;
    [cellView addSubview:imgView];


    CGRect idLabelRect = CGRectMake(65, 0, 190, 18);
    idLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:idLabelRect] autorelease];
    idLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    idLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    idLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    idLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    idLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    idLabel.tag = 0;

    CGRect statusRect = CGRectMake(65, 22, 190, 22);
    statusLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusRect] autorelease];
    statusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    statusLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    statusLabel.tag = 1;

    CGRect orderDateRect = CGRectMake(65, 48, 190, 22);
    orderDate = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:orderDateRect] autorelease];
    orderDate.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    orderDate.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    orderDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    orderDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    orderDate.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    orderDate.tag = 2;

    CGRect byRect = CGRectMake(65, 75, 190, 22);
    byLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:byRect] autorelease];
    byLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    byLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    byLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    byLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    byLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    byLabel.tag = 3;

    CGRect totalRect = CGRectMake(65, 98, 190, 22);
    totalLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:totalRect] autorelease];
    totalLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    totalLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    totalLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    totalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    totalLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    totalLabel.tag = 4;

    [cellView addSubview:idLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:statusLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:orderDate];
    [cellView addSubview:byLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:totalLabel];

}

cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];
idLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:0];
statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];
orderDate = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:2];
byLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:3];
totalLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:4];

x = [records count];
//NSLog(@" total number of row: %d",x);
if(y<x){
    NSLog(@"%d",y);
    //[self performSelector:@selector(tabledata:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:y]  afterDelay:0.0];
    if(y == indexPath.section){
    idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Id: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:0]];
    statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:1]];
    orderDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:2]];
    byLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:3]];
    totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:4]];
    y++;

    }
}
```

Code for refresh table...

```
  - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if (isLoading) return;
isDragging = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if (isLoading) {
    // Update the content inset, good for section headers
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0){
        NSLog(@"scrollView.contentOffset.y 1= %d",scrollView.contentOffset.y );
        tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= -REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT){
        NSLog(@"scrollView.contentOffset.y 2= %d",scrollView.contentOffset.y  );
        tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    }
} else if (isDragging && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
    // Update the arrow direction and label
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT) {
        // User is scrolling above the header
        NSLog(@"scrollView.contentOffset.y 3= %d",scrollView.contentOffset.y      );
        refreshLabel.text = self.textRelease;
        [refreshArrow layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
    } else { // User is scrolling somewhere within the header
        refreshLabel.text = self.textPull;
        [refreshArrow layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI * 2, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
   }
}

 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
   if (isLoading) return;
   isDragging = NO;
   if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT) {
    // Released above the header
    [self startLoading];
   }
 }


return cell;
}
```

is there any further question then please tell me..i need this solution very much early....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change "MyIdentifier" to "nil" 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

Hope this work!Peace

Comment: Can anyone chime in with the root cause of why this is happening? Why does `nil` fix it?

Comment: I know this is old but Ill post the answer. This is not correct I repeat this is not correct. The point of dequeueReusableCEll is to reuse cells already placed in memory, doing this sort of functionality will cause you to have an infinite amount of cells in memory which eventually would cause your program to crash. The reason why this works is each and every cell is a brand new instance of UITableVIewCell. What tableviews do is reuse the same amount of cells in order to show data not load a new cell for every unseen row.